# Why Initialization is not required in EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am new to the Struts2 framework and to EJB as well. I have a class `LoginDAO` which implements `checkUser` method of an interface `LoginDAOLocal`. I don't understand why I see different behavior for the following scenarios:

If I use an EJB (`LoginDAO` is stateless session bean) as follows, method call works perfectly without any error.

```
@EJB
private LoginDAOLocal loginDao;
loginDao.checkUser(userName,password);
```

If I use Struts2 as follows, it gives a Null pointer exception for the method call.

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    // Getters setters for userName and password)
    private LoginDAOLocal loginDao;
    loginDao.checkUser(this.userName,this.password);
}
```

If I use a simple Java application (no EJB or Struts2), the method call creates a compile time error saying loginDao is not initialized

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LoginDAOLocal loginDao;
    loginDao.checkUser(userName,password);
}
```

Can someone explain why this different behavior ?

Comment: In the second case, `LoginDAOLocal` is not recognized as an EJB without the annotation `@EJB`. You need to have a JNDI in the last case (along with a class library, since they have to be remote EJBs).

Comment: The second one is not an EJB Application. Its in Struts2. So no annotations...

Comment: Struts2 doesn't know about EJBs because it's running its own container for actions and other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting too much into the Java EE spec: EJBs are managed by an EJB container that exists in J2EE servers (JBoss \ Websphere etc..). The container takes control of bean lifecycle and is responsible for creating \ destroying beans according to the application needs.

When running out of container (simple java application) your beans won't get initialized and you don't have a JNDI context to get beans from, even if you add @EJB annotation to the field member.

Comment: So in case of EJB's, the instance is created and managed by the container and hence we are not required to initialize while in case of Struts2 there is no container to create the instance hence we have to do it. is that the whole gist of it ?

Comment: If running within a J2EE server the EJB are managed and created but won't get injected to the Struts Action classes as they are managed by a different container. You have to manually inject the EJB Remote interfaces via JNDI or dependency injection as suggested in the other answers (Spring\Guice etc..).

In a standard Java application you cannot use EJBs, unless you use a third party library such as open-ejb which enables EJB management outside of a J2EE server.

Answer (score 1):

We can say that there are two ways to manage the beans, using the container (managed by the container), or by another component (managed by a servlet, listener or filter).

Using components managed by the container, the container injects the references. e.g.:

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/TestDS")
    private DataSource testDS;

}
```

By contrast, a component managed by a bean, e.g.:

```
@Namespace("/User")
@ResultPath(value = "/")
@Result(name = "success", location = "pages/login.jsp")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

}
```

is managed by the filter [`org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html). The latter should be responsible for performing [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/beans.html), for example, takes care of injecting all necessary dependencies.

Comment: `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3. `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` should now be used instead :)